# pandas set columns based on values of the same column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
userid       date
  1        2010-01-03
  2        2009-01-04
  3        2004-02-03
  1        2007-01-01
```

I want to create a column that outputs true if there is another similar userid in another row with an earlier date. i.e.

```
userid       date        userid_seen
  1        2010-01-03        t
  2        2009-01-04        f
  3        2004-02-03        f
  1        2007-01-01        f
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work by calling `apply` and passing param `axis=1` to apply it row-wise:

```
In [88]:

def func(x):
    if len(df.loc[(df['userid'] == x.userid) & (df['date'] != x.date), 'date']) > 0:
        return (df.loc[(df['userid'] == x.userid) & (df['date'] != x.date), 'date'] < x.date).values.max()
    return False
df['user_id_seen'] = df.apply(lambda row: func(row), axis=1)
df
Out[88]:
   userid       date user_id_seen
0       1 2010-01-03         True
1       2 2009-01-04        False
2       3 2004-02-03        False
3       1 2007-01-01        False
```

**UPDATE**

Although the above works it will be slow for large dataframes as @MattiJohn correctly points out as this effectively iterates over each row.

The following is a more compact answer similar to @MattiJohn's answer:

```
In [102]:

df['user_id_seen'] = df.groupby('userid')['date'].transform('min') < df.date
df
Out[102]:
   userid       date user_id_seen
0       1 2010-01-03         True
1       2 2009-01-04        False
2       3 2004-02-03        False
3       1 2007-01-01        False
```

Comment: This will perform pretty poorly on a large DataFrame because you are performing two slice operations for each row. It's generally better to  try to do things on the entire DataFrame rather than iteration because then you get to take advantage of numpy's optimisations.

Comment: @MattiJohn I agree, I think your answer is better, it's inspired a better answer from me

Comment: hmm at 664098 rows 10 mins later the processing is still not done. any idea?

Comment: @goh groupby operations can be very slow, plus what this is doing is returning a series with it's index aligned with the original dataframe, I'm not that surprised

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do this is to calculate the earliest date for each user ID, and then check whether the row has a more recent date. Assuming `df` is your DataFrame:

```
min_date = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('userid')['date'].agg({'min_date': min}))
df = df.merge(min_date, left_on='userid', right_index=True)
df['userid_seen'] = df.date > df.min_date
df = df[['userid', 'date', 'userid_seen']]  # get rid of the 'min_date' column
```